# How do I keep track of Bundler API changes?

Tags: rubygems, bundler

Please bear with me, I'm a gem authoring noob.

Thus far, I haven't even been able to find formal Bundler API documentation, so I'm having a hard time adhering to best practices and knowing what commands do what, and what api changes are happening aside from the small amount of docs on the [Bundler website](http://gembundler.com).

So my first gem was based off of Yehuda Katz's [newgem-template](http://github.com/wycats/newgem-template), which says to use

```
gem "newgem", :path => File.expand_path("..", __FILE__)
```

in the Gemfile to pull in deps from this gem's gemspec.  This seems to have gone out of favor for a `gemspec` command in the Gemfile, which I can only presume does the same thing. (can someone point me to the docs on this)

Next he says to use:

```
require "bundler"
Bundler.setup
```

in your Rakefile which I guess requires all the files in your Gemfile ??  Again it appears this has gone out of favor (according to the generated code from new `bundle gem some_gem` with bundler 1.0.0RC4) for:

```
require 'bundler'
Bundler::GemHelper.install_tasks
```

Which I can only guess is loading rake tasks...  So what happened to `Bundler.setup`?  What was this even doing?  As a new gem author I'm finding it increasingly difficult to stick to best practices when I can't even find documentation on what those practices should be.

I know it's still in beta, but a helpful hint along the way to stable with each release would help me out a great deal.

Anyway can someone explain my Q's above and maybe point me to the docs/api on Bundler (aside from http://gembundler.com which I'm aware of)

Answer (score 1):

Andre Arko (head contributor of Bundler) did a nice webinar for EngineYard last week and addresses the changes with `Bundler.setup` in 1.0x I forget the details, but the presentation is here [at this link](http://www.engineyard.com/video/13917022?mkt_tok=3RkMMJWWfF9wsRonvaXPZKXonjHpfsX56u4vUK%2bg38431UFwdcjKPmjr1YUJSNQhcOuuEwcWGog8xQJfE%2b6QZYFS/g==).